# What are applications like IdeaBox called?

Tags: open-source, name

I'm trying to figure out the generic name for systems that allows users to contribute with the development of new features. Kickass Torrents has a very interesting app in it's site named IdeaBox and it's divided in stages such as: suggestions, planned, in progress, completed. It has a voting feature for everyone with more than 100 reputation and that's pretty much all. I wanna look at opensource alternatives but that's not possible if I don't know how it's generically named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any especially unique name for these, just them referred to as suggestion boxes.

[All Our Ideas](http://www.allourideas.org/) operates as a service, but the software is open and [available on Github](https://github.com/allourideas).
[BBYIDX](http://bbyidx.com/) is a similar offering that oddly enough had its start [at Best Buy](http://forums.bestbuy.com/t5/Best-Buy-IdeaX/idb-p/IdeaX).
If you want to get more hands-on, the [WordPress Ideas](http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/)(and [Kvetch](http://wordpress.org/extend/kvetch/)) areas are almost certainly built on WordPress, via some combination of user submission form, voting plugin and the built-in registration system.